# useEffect looping issue

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Here I have a useSessionStorage I've created and another I've found. One works as expected, the other loops. Can someone ELI5 the issue with setValue?

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-rgb-ibm33?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Along with sharing the code-sandbox link, could you please add the code snippet where you are facing issues/problems?

Answer (score 0):

- you should monitor value, add vlaue to useEffect listening list. useEffect will listen the change of the target.

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useSessionStorage("my-key", "foo");
  const before = value;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("value");
  }, [value, before]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Value: {value}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setValue("bar")}>bar</button>
      <button onClick={() => setValue("baz")}>baz</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to monitor something that gets resolved by an api call. Once that resolves, I want to save that to sessionStorage. My understanding is that I would have to include setValue in the useEffect.

Comment: @blu So, sessionStorage operations should be in the useEffect body. when value change, then step into useEffect body, at last, wirite vlaue to storage.

Comment: That is when I encounter the looping.

Comment: @blu useEffect is hooked for side effect, e.g. logging. if you would like to write sessionStorage, you had better to onChange or other hooks.

Comment: @blu you also can make copy of source variable, add into watchling list. I have update my code.Can you accept that?